# Grunt: issue with line endings

Tags: javascript, windows, gruntjs, yeoman, mean-stack

I'm working on a MEAN-stack project, and I'm the only one in the team who is using Windows (changing to unix is not an option in this case).

I have a problem with Windows's CRLF line endings. Every time I run Grunt serve, it generates few files (index.html and some .scss) for our project. After I make some changes to the code, I need to commit the changes with GIT.

The problem is that, I have unix LF line endings in every other file that I have edited except the ones that GRUNT has generated. How can I change GRUNT to generate files with unix LF line endings in Windows environment instead of CRLF?

Comment: Maybe try cygwin? Is grunt itself generating the files, or is it calling something else that is generating the files?

Comment: I didn't try cygwin, instead I added the lines below into .gitattributes to fix this problem and it worked prefectly! Thanks anyways!

`*.css text eol=lf
*.html text eol=lf`

Check: [link] https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.gitattributes

Comment: You can use `grunt.util.linefeed = '\n';` in your gruntfile to force all plattforms to `\n` as eol char